# I seem to be retaining self inside a block even when using an indirect __block reference to it, perhaps cause of copying the block to the heap?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

**[EDIT: Since it was causing confusion, this whole case assumes MRR and not ARC]**

I'm having an odd (there's an explanation obviously, I just can't figure it out) behavior with a block which references self (indirectly) and is in turned copied to another object's property (that is, copied from object As' stack to the heap and retained by an object B). If the block doesn't contain the reference to _this, Object A's dealloc is called every time it is popped from a navigation controller, as it should. However, if the block references _this, the object's (MyObjectA in the code below) dealloc is only called every other time. That is, I push this view controller subclass, createBlock is called, I pop and nothing happens. I push again, createBlock is called again, then pop and then it DOES call dealloc on MyObjectA.

For the sake of brevity, I'm only posting the snippets I believe are key to the behavior.

Say I have an object MyObjectA (sublcass of a custom UIViewController), which includes a method createBlock, like so:

```
- (void)createBlock
{
  __block MyObjectA* _this = self;
  int(^animationBlock)(NSArray*,NSDictionary*);


  animationBlock =
  ^(NSArray* layers, NSDictionary* parameters)
  {
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:
     ^{
       for(CALayer* layer in layers)
         layer.opacity = 1;
     }];

    CABasicAnimation* a2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    a2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.];
    a2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.];
    a2.duration = .4;
    a2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    a2.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    a2.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    CABasicAnimation* a = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    a.duration = .4;
    a.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    a.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    a.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    CAAnimationGroup* g = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    g.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a,a2, nil];
    g.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    g.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    g.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    CALayer* numberLayer;
    CALayer* flechaLayer;
    CGFloat timeOffset = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < [layers count]; i+=2)
    {
      numberLayer = [layers objectAtIndex:i];
      flechaLayer = [layers objectAtIndex:i+1];

      a2.beginTime = [_this.view.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] + timeOffset;
      [numberLayer addAnimation:a2 forKey:nil];

      a2.beginTime = 0;
      a.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:flechaLayer.frame.origin.x + 100];
      a.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:flechaLayer.frame.origin.x + flechaLayer.frame.size.width / 2.];
      g.duration = 3;
      g.beginTime = [_this.view.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] + timeOffset + .4;
      [flechaLayer addAnimation:g forKey:nil];

      timeOffset += 1.5;
    }

    [CATransaction commit];

    return 0;
  };

  [[AnimationFactory sharedFactory] registerAnimationBlock:animationBlock forKey:@"EnsureFlechasNutricion"];
}
```

As you can see, there's a reference to _this in the animation block. 
Then, the AnimationFactory's (a singleton) method which registers the blocks is:

```
- (void)registerAnimationBlock:(int(^)(NSArray*, NSDictionary*))animationBlock forKey:(NSString*)key
{
  int(^heapBlock)(NSArray*, NSDictionary*) = [animationBlock copy];
  [self.animationBlocks setObject:heapBlock forKey:key];
  [heapBlock release];
}
```

My guess is that copying the block to the heap is retaining MyObjectA, or perhaps adding the block to the NSMutableDictionary in the AnimationFactory.. but I'm not sure.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused - you have the block variable `this` declared, then there's `_this`, where is that coming from?

Comment: sorry, typo.. I just corrected it. _this is the declaration before the block declaration

Comment: I don't think the code above can cause `self` to be retained by the block, since `self` is not used inside the block. Either you are doing something wrong somewhere else, you have a buggy compiler, or you are inadvertently using ARC for that file (MyObjectA implementation file)

Answer (score 0):

*[Update: this answer applies when using ARC and from the comments it turns out MRC is being used, so its not the answer!]*

The `__block` attribute is for when you need a variable which can be updated by a block, i.e. the variable is passed to the block *by reference* rather than *by value* as is the default case. This does not appear to be needed in your code, you don't update the value of `_this` within your block.

To break a strong reference cycle use the `__weak` attribute. Your current `_this` is a strong reference to the same object that `self` references, so your block ends up with a strong reference.

Comment: Actually, pre-ARC you used `__block` to do this, if I recall correctly.

Comment: are you sure about that? I know that __block is for modifying the variable, but I'm pretty sure __weak only applies to ARC, which I'm not using, and "standard" way of pulling a weak is by doing __block whatever* identifier = rval so that I end up effectively with a mere reference and the retain count is not modified

Comment: In MRR mode, `__block` is how you avoid retaining the referenced object. In ARC, the same function is accomplished using `__unsafe_unretained` or `__weak`.

Comment: right. So still a mistery why my object's dealloc gets called only every other time

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz - oops, yes I had assumed ARC. Modified the answer to note this for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out: When I add the newly copied (heap) block to the AnimationFactory's dictionary, I'm necessarily retaining self even if doing the weak reference shebang when originally declaring the block in self.

The solution is to get a weak (aka __block Class* identifier = eval since I'm not on ARC) reference to self.view, which is the reason I was referencing self to start with, as opposed to one to self. This way, in spite of this view's reference count increasing, self's ref count stays correct. Then, on pop, self is not retained by the AnimationFactory's dictionary and does call dealloc.

I should mention that self's dealloc includes a call to another method which in turn removes all registered blocks from the AnimationFactory, bringing self.view's retain count back to normal too implicitly, and thus not leaking.

Comment: what? I don't get it. Where in the block are you using `self` that will cause the block to retain it?

Comment: The code itself is not, not in the regular sense. What happens is, the block uses __block MyObjectA* _this = self. This at first glance takes care of not retaining self. But later I copy the block to the heap and then add it to another object's collection. This causes _this to be retained anyway, somehow. Then by the time the object pointed to should dealloc, evidently there's still something preventing it from being released. If instead I reference just the view, the same applies but self's dealloc decreases the view's count and removing the animationblock from the other obj further decs it.

Comment: @SaldaVonShwartz: What you are saying is incorrect. First of all, it is *exactly* when the block is copied that captured objects are retained in the first place in MRC. So when we are talking about the block retaining stuff, we are talking about when it is copied. And the whole point of `__block` is that it does not get retained when the block is copied.

Comment: I don't get it. you are kind of saying the same thing I am." First of all, it is exactly when the block is copied that captured objects are retained in the first place in MRC" - eh.. yes. That's way I'm saying that in spite of using _this, self is retained. Then you go on to say that __block implies non-retention on copy and I can tell you it does. That's why dealloc wasn't getting called

Comment: basically, __block id _this = self prevents retaining while the block is on the stack, the minute it gets copied to the heap, _this is retained anyway. That's why I instead switched to using a ref to self.view and not self itself

Comment: by the way, when I said "and I can tell you it does" I meant "I can tell you it does retain on copy", regardless of the block referencing __block _this and not self directly

Comment: @user102008 I don't get it either, something else must be going on. I even made a sample project getting as close as I could to this problem, with some simplifications - using a block type like `void (^blockName)()` and just keeping an `NSMutableArray` to add the block copies to. I experience no such retain cycle - every time the view controller is popped off the stack it gets deallocated. I've posted a zip of it. Launch it, tap the plus, tap the cell, then tap back - every time you'll get the log indicating dealloc. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11613111/Block%20Weirdness.zip

Comment: To follow up, I modified it to be even more like the real problem, providing a method in the app delegate that copies the block and adds it to a mutable dictionary. I am still unable to reproduce the issue. This is incredibly strange!

Comment: wow... weird. I'll check out your sample. Though in my app, just changing the use of a __block ref to self inside the block to a __block ref to self.view solved the problem. Which is why I concluded the heap copy must have been retaining the __block ref to self (the _this pointer inside my block)

Comment: Understood, that is so strange! What version of iOS was this on by the way? And glad it is working for you now by the way!

Comment: iOS 6 now. But same was happening with SDK5